# Why doesn't my RangeEditor work, when I use mode='spinner'?

Tags: spinner, enthought, traitsui

In a *HasTraits* subclass, I have the following *Trait* defined:

```
tx_lane_sel = Range(0, 12)
```

If I display it in my *View*, using:

```
Item('tx_lane_sel')
```

it works as expected, displaying a slider bar, which ranges from 0 to 12.
However, if I try to display it, using:

```
Item('tx_lane_sel', editor=RangeEditor(mode='spinner'))
```

the resultant spinner only offers me choices '0' and '1'!

**How do I get the spinner working correctly? That is, how do I get it to offer me the full range [0, 12]?**

Answer (score 0):

The RangeEditor is not especially ment for Range traits. Thus, as for integers or floats, you need to specify the range by using the `low=0, high=12` or the `low_name` or `high_name` editor factory attributes:

```
 Item("tx_lane_sel", editor=RangeEditor(low=0, high=12, mode='spinner'))
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, but why can't a spinner be auto-initialized with the appropriate limits, just as the default widget (slider bar, I believe) is?